# Ring homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A,B$ be rings with identity and let $f:A \to B$ be a (unital) ring homomorphism. We know that $A$ and $B$ can be regarded as $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras. If $\tilde{f}:A \to B$ is a unital $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra homomorphim then it is a (unital) ring homomorphism. I wondered if the converse was also true. For  $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \in A$ we have
\begin{align}
f(k\cdot x) &= f((\underbrace{1_A+\dots+1_A}_\textrm{k times})x) \\
&= f( \underbrace{x+\dots+x}_\textrm{k times}) \\
&= \underbrace{f(x)+\dots+f(x)}_\textrm{k times} \\
&= (\underbrace{1_B+\dots+1_B}_\textrm{k times})f(x) \\
&= k \cdot f(x), 
\end{align}
and so $f$ is in fact an algebra homomorphism (assuming that all of the above is correct). So if I regard $A$ and $B$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras it doesn't really matter if say that there is a (unital) ring homomorphism between them or that there is a (unital) algebra homomorphism between them since they're essentially the same thing?

Comment: This is correct (provided that you interpret the equations correctly when $k < 0$).  It's also sufficient to observe that $f(k) = k$ if $k \in \mathbb Z$, viewed as an element of $A$ (resp. $B$).  The point is that there's a unique unital ring map from $\mathbb Z$ to anything, and this forces the composition $\mathbb Z \to A \to B$ to agree with the map $\mathbb Z \to B$.

Comment: @RaviFernando I see. Thank you!